# Android - Crashlytics, run code during crash

Tags: android, error-handling, crashlytics

I had a bad crash case that was caused due to some Asyncs doing stuff in improper order in a SQLite and thing blew up. It took me some time to debug all that and access to the internal db would have helped immensely. I know how to access that internal db on a dev device but in case something goes wrong I would like to be able to get an instance of that db no matter the device. For error reporting I am using Crashlytics.

The question is: Is there a way to have Crashlytics run a piece of code (method, etc) during the crash collection/reporting? (For example, get db copy and email it, or something)

Couldn't find something in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get control prior to Crashlytics logging a crash. You essentially have to create your own uncaught exception handler and call Crashlytics' handler from there. Something like this in your Application class:

```
private UncaughtExceptionHandler originalUncaughtHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // initialize Fabric with Crashlytics

    originalUncaughtHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);

    // do the rest of your oncreate stuff
}

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    // do your work to add data to Crashlytics log

    originalUncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
}
```

Comment: Combining the two other answers here, I was afraid I would have to do something like this. Was hoping for the simple way out. The reason someone would use an error logging tool to begin with is to not delve into the uncaught exceptions. Well uncaught exceptions it is. Thank you for the  answer and the "sneak peek" on how to set it up.

(To Crashlytics devs... more power to the people!!! :P )

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You can however set certain values before initiating Crashlytics. Like adding values to parameters so as to identify user. Like adding email id of user before creating a crashlytics session.

Answer (score 0):

As @basu-singh said, you can add context to the crash, see https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Or you can use your own UncaughtExceptionHandler, and then call Crashlytics. Though your code needs to be extra safe !